# How to fill a dictionary with two sets?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a Card class, which has methods to access the card rank and suit separately.

```
class Card:

   def __init__(self, v, p):
      self.value = v
      self.naipe = p

   def get_value(self):
      return self.value

   def get_naipe(self):
      return self.naipe

   def get(self):
      return (self.value, self.naipe)
```

And I also have a function to return the mixed deck, and another one to return just one card. Obs: these functions do not belong to card class

```
def shuffle_pack():
   pack = []
   naipes = {'\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663'}
   values = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 'Q', 'J', 'K', 'A'}

   for value in values:
      for naipe in naipes:
         pack.append(Card(value, naipe))
        
   random.shuffle(pack)

   return pack

def return_card(pack):
   card = pack.pop()
   return card
```

Execution example:

```
 pack = shuffle_pack()
 distribui_carta(pack).get_naipe()
```

> '♡'

```
 pack = shuffle_pack()
 distribui_carta(pack).get_value()
```

> '3'

```
pack = shuffle_pack()
distribui_carta(pack).get()
```

> ('2', '♠')

Instead of the list I want to use a dictionary and fill it with both sets. Where the first set, referring to the values ​​of the keys, are the suits of the deck, and the values ​​of the deck correspond to the values ​​in the dictionary. What I'm looking for is something similar to the append method of list, to make this "concatenation" between keys and values.

I want to do this to get the value and suit of a given card separately without using the Card class.

Comment: Can you show an example of the dictionary you're hoping to produce? From your description I have little idea what you want. Something like `{'♡': ['2', '3', '4']}` (but with more suits and values)?

Comment: Yes, that would be exactly it. Each suit would have its values. However, what I intend is to implement a for in a similar way to the list, and go adding the values ​​to a given suit, and then add them to an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
suits_to_values_dict = {suit: list(values) for suit in suits}
```